# Nextflow Not a valid path value: 'status' Error

Tags: nextflow

I am trying to run a nextflow pipeline and getting the error as shown below

```
module load nextflow/23.04.3
nextflow run main.nf -ansi-log false -profile singularity,cluster --outdir /cluster/work/pipeline_runs/RNA/outdir
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.3
Launching `main.nf` [silly_shirley] DSL2 - revision: 4c6c61737a
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'fastqc (1)'

Caused by:
  Not a valid path value: 'status'


Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
Execution cancelled -- Finishing pending tasks before exit
```

Here are the error contents of the `.nextflow.log` file. The path `/cluster/work/nextflow-rna_seq` is where my nextflow pipeline is, nextflow is looking for a `bin` folder in this path

```
Feb-06 07:07:55.762 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Script base path does not exist or is not a directory: /cluster/work/nextflow-rna_seq/bin
......
......
Feb-06 07:07:59.181 [Actor Thread 3] ERROR nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Error executing process > 'fastqc (1)'

Caused by:
  Not a valid path value: 'status'
```

Comment: Nextflow always looks for a `bin` folder in the launch directory. This is not what is causing this valid path error. It has to do with what you're passing as path. Try absolute path, for example, at some early point so that Nextflow can know what you're referring to.

Comment: it sounds like the string value "status" was passed as an input to a process expecting a `path` input